# how to remove multiple elements by index from a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, slice

I have a multi dimension array like this

```
 $state=array(array('state'=>t,'capital=>'y'),array('state'=>'p','capital'=>'q'),array('state'=>,'l','capital'=>'s'),array('state'=>'g','capital=>'h'));
```

I need to form a sub array by removing one or more indexes in random order from this array lets say $state[1],$state[3]
output is

```
  $new_state=array(array('state'=>t,'capital=>'y'),array('state'=>'g','capital=>'h'));
```

is there any direct function to achieve this?

Comment: show your expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first array 3 element index like `0`,`1`,`2`. Used `unset()` for delete array element by array indexing like `unset($state[1])` or more... Now array index is `0`, `2`. it is un serialize. For retrieve correct indexing serial used `array_values()`. Now final array index is `0`,`1`

```
<?php                  
$state=array(array('state'=>'t','capital'=>'y'),array('state'=>'p','capital'=>'q'),array('state'=>'g','capital'=>'h'));

unset($state[1]);
$new_array = array_values($state);;
print_r($new_array);
?>
```